# WordPress Visual Editor Filter for Visual View

Tags: hook, wordpress

I have setup custom HTML to be created when a user inserts media using "Add Media" in WordPress using the code below:

```
add_filter('get_image_tag', 'add_image_frames', 10, 6);

function add_image_frames($html, $id, $alt, $title, $align, $size) {
    $html = '
        <div class="image-container">
          <noscript 
              data-src-small="'.wp_get_attachment_image_src($id,'small', false)[0].'" 
              data-src-medium="'.wp_get_attachment_image_src($id,'medium', false)[0].'" 
              data-src-large="'.wp_get_attachment_image_src($id,'large', false)[0].'"
              data-alt="'.$alt.'"
              data-title="'.$title.'"
              data-class="align'.$align.'">

            <img src="'.wp_get_attachment_image_src($id,'medium', false)[0].'">
          </noscript>
        </div>';

    return $html;
}
```

This works fine if you are working in the "Text" mode but when I move to the "Visual" mode it displays the same HTML, is there a filter I can use to change the output of the visual mode to something that can be seen by the user during the creation of the page?

Thanks

Comment: Try asking at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/, you might have better luck there.

Comment: Ok, I will try it there :)